# UNIX/SED - Wildcard in file name

Tags: sed, filenames, wildcards, csv

File name is: file_201909091143.csv

How to add a wildcard to pull all files that start with 'file' ?

```
#!/bin/bash
#cleans blank rows
sed -i '/^$/d' file?.csv #wildcard missing
```

UPDATE
directory's ls:

```
drwxr-x--- 2 user user  324 Aug 29 16:27 0085
-rw-r----- 1 user user  168 Sep  3 10:03 file.sh
-rw-r----- 1 user user 5779 Sep  3 10:57 file.sql
-rw-r----- 1 user user  726 Sep  4 15:07 split_script.sh
-rw-r----- 1 user user   51 Sep  4 16:13 tst.sh
-rw-r----- 1 user user 21205 Sep  4 16:20 file_20190808134503.csv
```

Script is trigged as follows:

```
bash tst.sh
```

Comment: `No such file or directoryitions..csv`

Comment: use `*` instead of `?`

Comment: `No such file or directoryitions?.csv`

Comment: Don't edit Unix files on MS Windows. Your file seems to have CRLF line endings. Run `dos2unix yourscript` to fix it.

Comment: I'm logged on RHEL machine and writing script using Mobaxterm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @msp9011 mentioned you probably need to swap your ? with a * to allow for multiple character matching.

[Wildcards](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) discusses the bash interpenetration of wildcard characters. Stating a ? "can represent any single character", while a * "can represent any number of characters"

```
$ cat run.sh 
#!/bin/bash
#cleans blank rows
sed -i '/^$/d' file*.csv
$ cat file_201909091143.csv 
line1

line3
$ ./run.sh 
$ cat file_201909091143.csv 
line1
line3
```

Comment: After adding `*` I get error: `:No such file or directoryitions*.csv`

Comment: @marcin2x4 That's because you've changed the script from what's presented in this answer to something else, and used a filename globbing pattern that does not match anything.

Comment: Oh I believe I see what @stephane is seeing, your output looks like it is backing up on itself. Which commonly happens with unexpected newline characters. Looks like Mobaxterm is a windows X emulator. So it is probably using CRLF line endings. Try running `dos2unix <yourscript>` then run your script again.

Comment: `dos2unix` didn't help

Comment: Could you post an ls of the directory you are working with?

Comment: Also could you post the output of:
file <yourscript>
?

Comment: Based on file size I'm guessing your replace script is tst.sh? If so how are you running it, if not, which script is it?

Comment: `bash tst.sh` is how I trigger the script

Comment: Thanks. Could you post the output of `file tst.sh` ?

Comment: It's a simple CSV file with few `,` delimitted attributes

Comment: Oh sorry, 'file' is a command. I'm not interested in the file_20190808134503.csv file, I want to see the output of running `file tst.sh` which will give some information on your script file. It might be that you ran `dos2unix file_20190808134503.csv` which won't help. If that was the case try `dos2unix tst.sh` then running `bash tst.sh`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98300/discussion-between-marcin2x4-and-amos).